# Adding option from array in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am new to Redux-form. Here is the requirement, there are a text box and a button. Once the button is clicked the entered text is added to an array, and I need to add those elements of the array as a dropdown in the redux form. The text box and button are part of another component, and I need to get the array data in the Redux form (another comp) so as to render it as the options for the dropdown.

Could you please help me with the code in a bit detailed manner?

Comment: Hi..Can you post what have you tried so far??

Comment: I just used map to try to render the options. Seems like it's not how it is supposed to be done.

Comment: If you have the choice, please note that the redux FAQ and the redux style guide advise against having form state in redux.
https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#should-i-put-form-state-or-other-ui-state-in-my-store
https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux

Even the creators of redux-form themselves advise against it unless strictly necessary: https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form#%EF%B8%8F-attention-%EF%B8%8F

Comment: could you share the code ?